# player.duration shows always zero in MPMoviePlayerController for video file

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing a small video in mpmediaplayer controller using this code

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                   initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videostr]];
```

where videostr is path of that video file.

Now i need to get length of that video file for that i am using this code.

```
length = player.duration;
```

But it always shows 0.000. But the video is playing well.

I am checking by googling every where code to get video duration is `player.duration` only.

And i try some other code also

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videostr] 
                                             options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey, nil]] autorelease];
NSTimeInterval duration; 
if (asset) 
    duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration) ;
NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> %f", asset.duration);
```

even though it shows zero.Can any one please help me.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can not get a useful duration until the content is actually playable.

Register for load state changes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Evaluate the state once being notified:

```
- (void)MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ((player.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) == MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK)
    {
        NSLog(@"content play length is %g seconds", player.duration);
    }
}
```

Comment: notification : MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
call 2 times automatiaclly

Comment: If for default the video is paused this solution not work, because this notification is called when the user execute play action. Exist any way for get the duration before?

Answer (score 2):

## SWIFT

You can do in **swift** like this

```
func getMediaDuration(url: NSURL!) -> Float64{
        var asset : AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset.assetWithURL(url) as AVURLAsset
        var duration : CMTime = asset.duration
        
        return CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(movieDurationAvailable:) 
                                         MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification object:nil];

- (void)movieDurationAvailable:(NSNotification *)notification {

        NSLog(@"content play length is %g seconds", moviePlayer.duration);


 }
```

Comment: Maybe expand on that answer a little bit.  With a code sample or something useful....

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch time duration from video file using below code.

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:VideoFileURL];

AVURLAsset *sourceAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];

CMTime duration = sourceAsset.duration;

double durationInSeconds = duration.value/duration.timescale;
```

In `durationInSeconds` variable you get the exact duration in seconds.