# MPMoviewPlayer calculate current time during video play

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

i want to calculate current time based on how much video is played, i am confused to use the property of durationWatched, can any one help me what should i do? or how to get current time of youtube video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a simple category on MPMoviePlayerController

You can get the current playback time using the **currentTimeMonitor** method:

```
[self.moviePlayerController currentTimeMonitor:^{
  NSLog(@"Current time %i",[moviePlayerController.lastRecordedPlaybackTime intValue]);            
}];
```

A timer call the block every second to give you the current playbacktime.

There is a repository on github:

https://github.com/AlbanPerli/MPMoviePlayerController-CurrentPlybackTimeMonitor

Comment: it gives me log message zero :(

Comment: Did you play the video? is your project using ARC?

Comment: i am playing my video

Comment: what should i do now?

Answer (score 3):

try below code

```
CGFloat currentPlayedTime = [movieController currentPlaybackTime];
```

hope its helpfull.

Comment: it didn t work for me i tried it :(

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful . Take the dates When it is started and stopped then do this .

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"14:10"];// Startdate
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:@"18:09"];// Stop date
NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
int hours = (int)interval / 3600;             // integer division to get the hours part
int minutes = (interval - (hours*3600)) / 60; // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes
NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", hours, minutes];
```

Comment: but why i will use date???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035995/player-duration-shows-always-zero-in-mpmovieplayercontroller-for-video-file